# Explode function returning single row

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I used the field type as Array. "Select col as sample_table" returns the below output.

```
["[-80.86598534884,35.53423185253291],[-80.86598789514547,35.53423048990488],[-80.86598794307857,35.53423046392442]"]
```

When I used

`select explode(col) 
 from sample_table`.

I get the output as below which is a single row.

```
[-80.86598534884,35.53423185253291],[-80.86598789514547,35.53423048990488],[-80.86598794307857,35.53423046392442]
```

I want the output in 3 rows as below.

```
[-80.86598534884655,35.53423185253291]

[-80.86598789514547,35.53423048990488]

[-80.86598794307857,35.53423046392442]
```

As i see in the hive tutorial, explode function should return multiple rows but i don't see it happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you have given appears as an array field having only one value. That entire  value is taken as array of size one by explode function and thereby returns the result in a single row.

Comment: Thanks madhu.. I used split function and then used explode function. It worked.